# Remove array items from array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I'm trying to write an array extension that will allow me to remove items from an array if they exist in another array. I will need to use this for a range of custom types so was trying to build something generic.

This is what I have so far which returns the error "binary operator == cannot be applied to two t operands"

```
extension Array{


    mutating func removeArrayItems<T>(itemsToRemove: [T]){

        for item in itemsToRemove{
            var removed = removeObject(item)
        }
    }


    mutating func removeObject<T>(object: T) -> Bool {
        for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
            if let to = objectToCompare as? T {
                if object == to {
                    self.removeAtIndex(idx)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality operator, `==`, only applies to objects that are `Equatable`.  You need to qualify your type `T` as `T:Equatable`.  As such:

```
mutating func removeObject<T:Equatable>(object: T) -> Bool {
  // ...
}
```

Same with `removeArrayItems`

Note that if you are defining your own types, such as with `class` or `struct`, your types will also need to conform to `Equatable`.  Like this:

```
class Foo : Equatable {
  // ...
}

public func ==<T:Foo> (lhs:T, rhs:T) -> Bool {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for that. Got that compiling now. However the issue I still have is I can't seem to call this with arrays of custom type. It however works find on your standard types. 

e.g. var arrayTimings: [Timing] = [Timing]()
            //Populate array
            scheduledTimings.removeArrayItems(arrayTimings)